# How could I remove iOS simulator without uninstall Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There is a problem with my iOS simulator. I want to remove iOS 7.1 simulator from Xcode then download and install it again from XCode/Preferences/download tab. I couldn't find how to remove it.

How could I remove iOS Simulator without uninstall Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is open the iOS Simulator you want to uninstall and go to the menu in the top left and follow the path *iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...*

This'll delete all contents on the iOS Simulator.  This won't uninstall it, but it usually will fix it.

If your problem persists go to *~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator* and delete whatever version you want to delete.  I'm not 100% sure it'll reinstall next time you debug but it's worth a shot.  If it does manage to slip away though, you'll have to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: I tired both methods :(

Comment: The other other options are reinstalling Xcode or reinstalling Mac OS.  Can you give the exact error you're seeing?